# Static nav to fixed nav, causes page to "jump"

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

basically i have a navbar that becomes fixed when the user starts scrolling, with some transition stuff going on, to make it look nice.

My problem is, when my navbar becomes fixed, the whole page jumps up because the navbar is pulled out of the "stack", which means that when `scroll >= 100`, the page makes a small "jump" towards the top.

Obviously, i dont want my page to make glitchy jumps upon scrolling, so how do i fix this, in the most "correct" way?

One solution would be to make an invisible div behind the static navbar, to fill out the space. That would however require me to guess the height of the navbar. As well, this height change when the page is resized. - Therefore not a good solution in my opinion.

My jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
   var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

   if (scroll >= 100 && scroll < 200) 
   {
       $("#navbar").css({ "top": "-100px", "transition": "0.5s ease"});
       $("#navbar").removeClass('navbar-static-top');
   }

   else if (scroll >= 200)
   {
       $("#navbar").addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
       $("#navbar").css("top", "0px");
   }
   else if (scroll < 50) 
   {
       $("#navbar").css({ "top": "0px", "transition": "0s ease" });
       $("#navbar").addClass('navbar-static-top');
       $("#navbar").removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
    }
})
```

My Nav html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" id="navbar" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="navbar navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: When you make the nav fixed, add padding-top to the body of the size of the nav

Comment: Good solution, but that would require me to guess the height of the nav-bar, since the height is set to auto.

Comment: You don't have to guess it, just grab the computed height with jquery. You should account for browser resize as well.

Comment: Im gonna do that! was looking at this example here: http://flatsome.uxthemes.com/  

i can see they do the same!